# Structure without a tag

Tags: c, struct

If I declare a struct like this:

```
struct
{
   int a;
   char b;
} ident;
```

does that structure has a type? (i.e. an unspecified type, a default type, etc.).

Instead If I declare a struct like:

```
struct J
{
  int a;
  char b;
} ident;
```

we can say that `ident` is a stucture variabile of type `struct J`.

Comment: It has a type, but the type has no name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After

```
struct { int a; char b; } ident;
```

`ident` has an “anonymous structure type” and you won’t be able to declare another variable of the same type<sup>*)</sup>. That is, two anonymous structure types are never compatible. If you did, for example,

```
struct { int a; char b; } ident2;
```

afterwards, `ident` and `ident2` would be of different (though identical) type and an assignment like

```
ident2 = ident;
```

would be a constraint violation (a compiler must give a diagnostic message and may refuse to compile, what most compilers probably will).

---

<sup>*)</sup> Some compilers have extensions to allow it. For example, with Gcc, you can do:

```
typeof(ident) ident2 = ident;
```